# Elastic Search & Logstash performance

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-forwarder

Parsing logfiles with logstash taking much time.How can i increase the logstash performance.Hereare my scenario for 25mb it takes 30 mins exactly.Could anyone suggest me, how to increase the performance & also is this correct way to calculate the performance.My environment details AWS large instance with 15gb RAM.Thanks in advance for your responses

Comment: Assuming 200 byte messages you're clocking about 150 messages/s which isn't too bad if you have a bunch of filters. Are you maxing out the CPUs? Have you increased the filter workers beyond the default with `-w` or `--filterworkers`?

Comment: On top of what @MagnusBäck suggested, I would also check for the heap space allocated to logstash. are you outputting it to some other output also besides ElasticSearch (for ex. file, csv)?

Comment: Are you measuring logstash in a vacuum (stdin->filter->stdout)?  If not, you have other components that could be affecting the performance (elasticsearch, the network, etc).

Comment: @magnus i haven't used filter workers. Let me check about it BTW how could it maxing out cpus plz clarify.

Comment: @mufc yes i'm using jave heap size and outputing it with stdout & elastic search.

Comment: @let me use the filter and check it and remove the stdout which I have been used.

Comment: By maxing out the CPUs, I mean if you're at 100% CPU or if there are cycles to spare. `top` is a simple way of inspecting this. What numbers are you typically seeing on the `%Cpu(s)` row while you're doing this bulk processing? Which processes are typically at the top of the list? Oh, and how big is your Elasticsearch heap? With 15 GB RAM you should probably have a 7–8 GB JVM heap. With the 1 GB default heap you might be running into garbage collection delays during the bulk indexing.

Comment: top - 11:12:55 up 42 min,  2 users,  load average: 1.27, 1.17, 0.85
Tasks:  84 total,   1 running,  70 sleeping,  13 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 18.9%us,  3.4%sy,  0.0%ni, 61.8%id,  0.6%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si, 15.2%st ...   CPU's percentage is reached at higher of 21% where as for heap I already using 8g for Heap size.My question is how to increase the cpu percentage to 100% & how much filter worker count I should mention?

Comment: @user3751002 not utilizing the CPU at 100% is the whole idea behind the  diagnosis. You almost never want your CPU to go anywhere near 100. You can use more thread workers by including the flag `-w` `<number>` which will increase the number of concurrent threads. see if that improves the performance

Comment: Thread counts depends on?

Comment: Anyone give me suggestions how the filter worker thread counts depend on?Desperately looking out solution in this